# unable to import Android project, android.R not found

Tags: android, eclipse

i've downloaded a zip file contains an example project from [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html#views).

Now when i try to import in eclipse, R file is not generated (in gen folder, only BuildConfig.java is presend), so i couldn't launch example app. What's could be the problem?

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct API to build this project?

Comment: delete the gen folder, build your project and try again

Comment: Just change your Project Build Target to API 17 and the clean your project. The error will go away

Comment: You generally do not want to import android.R but rather the R file in your project's namespace.  If you are actually using something from android.R by its fully qualified name, and it is complaining it can't find *that*, then your problem is different from the one people are currently trying to answer.

Comment: target api already are 17.

Answer (score 1):

Just fix the errors that are stopping the R file from being generated (this is usually a naming issue with xml resource files for me, remember to not use caps in the xml file names), and then clean and build your project.

Also you should never add contents to the R file. Just add what you need in source and resources files and let it auto generate itself.